# I always get the latest data in the database

Tags: database, forms, get

I want to search and display data from database (data entered in a form). The problem is that I always get the last value in the database.
this is my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String nom, prenom;
            nom = tf3.getText();
            prenom = tf4.getText();
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/seminaire";
            String userid = "root";
            String password = "";
            try {
                if (nom != "" && prenom != "") {
                    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,
                            userid, password);
                    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM participant WHERE nom=nom && prenom=prenom");

                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        String nm = rs.getString("nom");
                        String prnm = rs.getString("prenom");
                        String cat = rs.getString("categorie");
                        String afl = rs.getString("affiliation");
                        String mnt = rs.getString("montant");  
                    } 
                 }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Have you any idea please.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the values you assign to nom and prenom aren't used in the query you execute. Also, should `&&` be `AND`?

I'd recommend using prepared statements to do so, see [Java documentation on prepared statements.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

I'd change your code to do something like this:

```
PreparedStatement selectStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM participant WHERE nom=? AND prenom=?");
selectStatement.setString(1, nom);
selectStatement.setString(2, prenom);
ResultSet rs = selectStatement.executeQuery();
```